# Why won't this python script generate the desired text file? (despite the script running with no errors)

Tags: python

This script is supposed to generate a text file of stock price values. I can't seem to either find the text file that is supposed to be generated from this script or have this script actually create the desired text file... I added a section of code to check if the file exists, but I keep getting the result that the text file is indeed not created. Please let me know what I can do to correct. When I run the code I do not get any errors. Thanks.

```
import urllib2
import time
import os
import sys

stockToPull = 'AAPL'

def pullData(stock):
    try:
        fileLine = stock+'.txt'
        urlToVisit = 'http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/'+stock+'/chartdata;type=quote;range=1y/csv'
        sourceCode = urllib2.urlopen(urlToVisit).read()
        splitSource = sourceCode.split('\n')

        for eachLine in splitSource:
            splitLine = eachLine.split(', ')
            if len(splitLine)==6:
                if 'values' not in eachLine:
                    saveFile = open(fileLine,'a') 
                    lineToWrite = eachLine+'\n'
                    saveFile.write(lineToWrite)

        print 'Pulled', stock
        print 'sleeping'

        if os.path.isfile(fileLine): # checks to see if text file created
            print "file does exist"
        else:
            print "No such file"

        time.sleep(5) 

    except Exception, e:
        print 'main loop', str(e)

pullData(stockToPull)
```

Comment: why are u checking len(splitLine)==6

Comment: there is no wrong in the code. i have checked it it created AAPL.txt

Comment: What OS are you running? I am on MAC OSX and still can't get the text file to generate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are splitting each row on the string `', '` (note the space). You should be splitting on the comma only:

```
for eachLine in splitSource:
    splitLine = eachLine.split(',')
    if len(splitLine)==6:
        # etc
```

You would be better off opening the file once, writing each line to it, then closing the file when finished. You can use a `with` statement to do this:

```
with open(fileLine, 'w') as outfile:
    for eachLine in splitSource:
        splitLine = eachLine.split(',')
        if len(splitLine) == 6 and 'values' not in eachLine:
            outfile.write('%s\n' % eachLine)
    outfile.close()
```

Comment: @gtr5fb : glad to hear it. Please upvote/accept this answer if you are satisfied :)

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to check whether data is arriving or not using

```
    from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError, HTTPError
    fileLine = stock+'.txt'
    urlToVisit = 'http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/'+stock+'/chartdata;type=quote;range=1y/csv'

    try:
        response = urlopen(urlToVisit)
        sourceCode = response.read()
        <place your logic here>
    except HTTPError as e:
        print 'The server couldn\'t fulfill the request.'
        print 'Error code: ', e.code

    except URLError as e:
        print 'We failed to reach a server.'
        print 'Reason: ', e.reason
```

your code works fine

output i got

```
  ['uri:/instrument/1.0/AAPL/chartdata;type=quote;range=1y/csv', 'ticker:aapl', 'Company-Name:Apple Inc.', 'Exchange-Name:NMS', 'unit:DAY', 'timestamp:', 'first-trade:19801212', 'last-trade:20140702', 'currency:USD', 'previous_close_price:59.7843', 'Date:20130703,20140702', 'labels:20130703,20130801,20130903,20131001,20131101,20131202,20140102,20140203,20140303,20140401,20140501,20140602,20140701', 'values:Date,close,high,low,open,volume', 'close:59.2929,94.2500', 'high:60.1429,95.0500', 'low:58.6257,93.5700', 'open:59.0857,94.7300', 'volume:28420900,266380800', '20140620,90.9100,92.5500,90.9000,91.8500,100813200', .....
'20140702,93.4800,94.0600,93.0900,93.8700,28420900', '']
    ['uri:/instrument/1.0/AAPL/chartdata;type=quote;range=1y/csv']
    ['ticker:aapl']
    ['Company-Name:Apple Inc.']
    ['Exchange-Name:NMS']
    ['unit:DAY']
    ['timestamp:']
    ['first-trade:19801212']
    ['last-trade:20140702']
    ['currency:USD']
    ['previous_close_price:59.7843']
    ['Date:20130703,20140702']
    ['labels:20130703,20130801,20130903,20131001,20131101,20131202,20140102,20140203,20140303,20140401,20140501,20140602,20140701']
    ['values:Date,close,high,low,open,volume']
    ['close:59.2929,94.2500']
    ['high:60.1429,95.0500']
    ['low:58.6257,93.5700']
    ['open:59.0857,94.7300']
    ['volume:28420900,266380800']
    ['20130703,60.1143,60.4257,59.6357,60.1229,60232200']
    ['20130705,59.6314,60.4700,59.3357,60.0557,68506200']
    ['20130708,59.2929,60.1429,58.6643,60.0157,74534600']
    ......
    ['20140630,92.9300,93.7300,92.0900,92.1000,49482300']
    ['20140701,93.5200,94.0700,93.1300,93.5200,38170200']
    ['20140702,93.4800,94.0600,93.0900,93.8700,28420900']
    ['']
    Pulled AAPL
    sleeping
    file does exist
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is fine, but I don't think it is able to do what you want or you don't know what you want. You haven't observed your data correctly. I have made minor changes to your script. Please run this script now:

```
import urllib2
import time
import os
import sys

stockToPull = 'AAPL'

def pullData(stock):
    try:
        fileLine = stock+'.txt'
        urlToVisit = 'http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/'+stock+'/chartdata;type=quote;range=1y/csv'
        sourceCode = urllib2.urlopen(urlToVisit).read()
        splitSource = sourceCode.split('\n')

        for eachLine in splitSource:
            splitLine = eachLine.split(', ')
            if len(splitLine)==6:
                print 'Entering outer'
                if 'values' not in eachLine:
                    print 'Entering innter'
                    saveFile = open(fileLine,'a')
                    lineToWrite = eachLine+'\n'
                    saveFile.write(lineToWrite)

        print 'Pulled', stock
        print 'sleeping'

        if os.path.isfile(fileLine): # checks to see if text file created
            print "file does exist"
        else:
            print "No such file"

        time.sleep(5)

    except Exception, e:
        print 'main loop', str(e)

pullData(stockToPull)
```

If you'd notice, I have just put two `print` statements inside the `if` blocks that actually write to a file. On running the script, I noticed that the `print` statements are never executed. So there are no errors in your code to my knowledge but it doesn't seem to be doing what you want it to. So re-check your data again.

Lastly, to solve these kind of problems, you must use the `pdb` library which stands for Python Debugger and it is an amazingly helpful tool to debug your code without making a mess of it. Checkout this [video from PyCon](http://pyvideo.org/video/644/introduction-to-pdb).

Comment: the code is working fine. i goot the staock value.may be it is happening since sometimes data is not recived by the using urlib2.may be the problem. there isno error in logic

Comment: Well, then the server is not sending the same response every time. Because I experienced the same problem when I ran the script.

Comment: Thank you so much for the changes and for the PDB library recommendation. I ran the script with your changes but still no file is generated.